# write a program that coutninues asking for a phrase and exclamation marks until you give the answer 0 for the exclamation marks

Tags: python, for-loop

Has to be a for loop.
I have this so far:

```
str = input('input phrase: ')
variable = int(input("exclamation marks: "))
for i in range(variable):
    str += "!"
print(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `while` loop and break when `variable = 0`:

```
while True:
    str = input('input phrase: ')
    variable = int(input("exclamation marks: "))
    if variable == 0: break  # exit loop
    for i in range(variable):
        str += "!"
    print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
variable = 1;
while(variable != 0)
str = input('input phrase: ')
variable = int(input("exclamation marks: "))
for i in variable:
     str += "!"
print(str)
```